# C++ syntax of 2D vector

Tags: c++, stl

Can someone explain below c++ syntax with example ?

```
vector <vector <int> > s(n,vector <int> ());
```

especially this part inside the constructor:

```
vector <int> ()
```

Comment: What's to explain? It's a vector of vectors of int. Nothing weird going on there.. hint; you may want to consult http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector - especially http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Answer (score 5):

This specific constructor of vector takes two arguments:

1. The number of elements.
2. The value to assign to each element.

For example, this creates a vector containing 3 times the value 5.

```
std::vector<int> vec(3, 5);
```

`vector<int>()` is a default-constructed instance of `vector<int>`. So you are creating a vector containing n vectors, each empty.

Comment: What is the terminology for the `vector<int>()` argument? A temporary or something else?

Comment: @Ron the technical term is a prvalue (aka "pure" rvalue)

Comment: Nitpick: *one* of the (multiple) vector constructors take such two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int N = 10;
    std::vector< std::vector<int> vector2DA(N, std::vector< int>(N));
    return 0;

}
```

This code create `vector2D` 10x10, first parameter constructor is size basic vector(vector2DA(size, objectWhichIsContain)), which contain other vector, which have size 10 (`std::vector< int>(size)`). We have `vector2D` 10x10.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `vector` of `vector`s is not exactly a "2D vector". The "rows" of `vector<vector<>>` are completely independent both in terms of memory layout and semantically. There are better options, e.g. [Boost.Multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).

Then we have `vector <int> ()`. Depending on context this could mean both temorary object initialization or a function declaration. The example in question actually does not provide enough context:

```
vector <vector <int> > s(n,vector <int> ());
```

If `n` happens to be a type name, then this line is a function declaration. Of course `n` is probably an `int`, but it would be better to explicitly state that you want a default-constructed `vector<int>` as a second argument:

```
vector <vector <int> > s(n,vector <int> {});
```

Here `vector <int> {}` unambiguously means *"a default-constructed temporary object of type `vector<int>`"*, and you pass it to the `vector<vector<int>>` constructor as a value to initialize your rows with.

This brings us to another observation: `std::vector` *value-initializes* its elements by default, which means that the same result can be achieved like that:

```
vector <vector <int> > s(n);
```

Finally, the presence of `vector<int>()` in the original statement kind of hints that it might have been intended to set up the "width" of the 2D vector:

```
vector <vector <int> > s(n,vector <int> (m));
```

but `m` got lost somewhere along the lines :)